# Matching a regular expression multiple times with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Noob question here. I have a very simple perl script and I want the regex to match multiple parts in the string

```
my $string = "ohai there. ohai";
my @results = $string =~ /(\w\w\w\w)/;
foreach my $x (@results){
    print "$x\n";
}
```

This isn't working the way i want as it only returns *ohai*. I would like it to match and print out *ohai ther ohai*

How would i go about doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Would this do what you want?

```
my $string = "ohai there. ohai";
while ($string =~ m/(\w\w\w\w)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

It returns

```
ohai
ther
ohai
```

From perlretut:

> The modifier "//g" stands for global matching and allows the
>   matching operator to match within a
>   string as many times as possible.

Also, if you want to put the matches in an array instead you can do:

```
my $string = "ohai there. ohai";
my @matches = ($string =~ m/(\w\w\w\w)/g);
foreach my $x (@matches) {
    print "$x\n";
}
```

Comment: +1. correct answer. You need the `g` modifier on the end of your regex.

Comment: thanks! I guess i needed to look more closely at the docs for that /g

Comment: It is useful to note that in "foreach", a "print $1" would only print the last "Ohai" for each time there is a pattern match (i.e. 3 times). Therefore, "while" seems to be the best choice when you have a pattern with several elements.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do this

```
my $string = "ohai there. ohai";
my @matches = split(/\s/, $string);
foreach my $x (@matches) {
  print "$x\n";
}
```

The split function in this case splits on spaces and prints

```
ohai
there.
ohai
```

Comment: Good suggestion but split here would return "there." with a dot. It would be better to do a "split(/\W+/, $string)" to get only the words.