# Assign to an array the substrings delimited by < >

Tags: perl

Is it possible to assign to an array the parts of a block of text that is delimited by `< >`. For example,

```
sometexthere <email@email.com> more text
more text moretext <another@email.com>
```

should produce

```
@array = qw(email@email.com another@email.com);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching a regular expression multiple times with Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374783/matching-a-regular-expression-multiple-times-with-perl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @array = $text =~ /<([^<>]+)>/g;
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. Could you explain to me how it works or what each character is doing (ie the ^ before <>) Thank you for the answer btw too.

Comment: `[^CHARS]` matches any one character that isn't in `CHARS`.